# How to get the significant pvalue for the correlation between two datasets in R?

Tags: r, correlation, p-value

I have two datasets in two data frames which are of different length. I'm trying to calculate the correlation between two data frames.

```
dput(data1)

structure(list(Samples = c("Sample1", "Sample2", "Sample3", "Sample4", 
"Sample5", "Sample6"), Gene1 = c(4.671302252, 4.047214831, 5.466179936, 
5.283893539, 4.755404471, 2.469735829), Gene2 = c(-2.597625581, 
-0.545400583, -1.760948089, -0.025914727, -4.506701651, -1.92244677
), Gene3 = c(4.518177333, 4.383227672, 5.175808561, 4.798211945, 
5.381003512, 3.755721129), Gene4 = c(6.176159142, 5.851062234, 
4.001055798, 4.923729009, 5.438633666, 5.398964894), Gene5 = c(5.292719633, 
5.118130958, 4.161460436, 3.802601359, 5.364577948, 4.084908402
), Gene6 = c(3.018843066, 4.250663843, 3.559959674, 5.120952707, 
3.00470538, 3.478294452), Gene7 = c(5.523144074, 5.213819135, 
6.910541399, 7.76544151, 6.71295831, 4.135405512), Gene8 = c(4.280905818, 
4.894985917, 5.691758253, 5.801298455, 5.801366783, 4.914515168
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

And the data2 looks like below:

```
dput(data2)

structure(list(Samples = c("Sample1", "Sample2", "Sample3", "Sample4", 
"Sample5", "Sample6"), B.cell = c(0.077235161, 0.083169074, 0.131076839, 
0.091987739, 0.104246383, 0.137797284), T.cell.CD4. = c(0.089704844, 
0.116399012, 0.179227307, 0.134534096, 0.143346971, 0.125001186
), T.cell.CD8. = c(0.19430495, 0.203269704, 0.211582459, 0.198538867, 
0.232369158, 0.165748405), Neutrophil = c(0.119542496, 0.130890002, 
0.130346653, 0.126705533, 0.119481998, 0.158515447), Macrophage = c(0.013270172, 
0.049023848, 0.036012432, 0.056938321, 0.149161503, 0.024486122
), Myeloid.dendritic.cell = c(0.437531368, 0.478689299, 0.493095004, 
0.503436218, 0.517459595, 0.550177096)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

I got the correlation co-efficient with `cor`.

```
data1 <- data.frame(data1[,-1], row.names = data1[,1])
data2 <- data.frame(data2[,-1], row.names = data2[,1])
cor(data1, data2, method="spearman")
```

[image]

But this doesn't give any p-values. And with some googling, I found `cor.test`. And this gave me an Error.

```
cor.test(data1, data2, method = "spearman")
Error in cor.test.default(data1, data2, method = "spearman") : 
  'x' and 'y' must have the same length
```

Is there a way to get the p-values with `cor` function? or How do I apply the `cor.test` function on this data for correlation co-efficient and pvalues?

Edit: As suggested I tried using `rcorr` but it looks like below:

```
res2 <- rcorr(as.matrix(data1, data2), type="spearman")
Warning message:
In if (rownames.force %in% FALSE) NULL else if (rownames.force %in%  :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

And the output:

[image]

But, I want the correlation between two data frames.

Comment: Look at function `rcorr` in package `Hmisc`.

Comment: @dcarlson thanq. I tried that but it gave a correlation between variables in the same data frame. I added the output to the above question. Please have a look. I want the output as I got from `cor`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rcorr`, but it gives you more than you need. Just extract what you want.

```
out <- rcorr(as.matrix(data1), as.matrix(data2), type="spearman")
```

`out` is a list with three matrices: `r`, `n`, and `p` containing correlations, number of observations, and p-values for all of the columns in both matrices. To get what you want just extract the columns/rows you need:

```
out$r[1:5, 6:8]
#       Neutrophil Macrophage Myeloid.dendritic.cell
# Gene4    -0.2571   -0.25714               -0.48571
# Gene5    -0.6000    0.08571               -0.31429
# Gene6     0.4857    0.14286               -0.14286
# Gene7    -0.5429    0.48571               -0.08571
# Gene8    -0.3714    0.82857                0.65714
out$P[1:5, 6:8]
#       Neutrophil Macrophage Myeloid.dendritic.cell
# Gene4     0.6228    0.62279                 0.3287
# Gene5     0.2080    0.87174                 0.5441
# Gene6     0.3287    0.78717                 0.7872
# Gene7     0.2657    0.32872                 0.8717
# Gene8     0.4685    0.04156                 0.1562
```

Comment: oh, I should have used `as.matrix` separately for both `data1` and `data2`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: small question. When I applied `rcorr` for bigger datasets, I see an ERROR like this. `Error in double(p * p) : vector size cannot be NA; In addition: Warning message: In p * p : NAs produced by integer overflow`

Comment: You may be running out of memory if the data set is very large. You may have to split the matrix into smaller chunks by extracting blocks and running them individually. There may be a function in another package that is designed specifically for large genetic data sets in bioconductor.